# IIs Can't redireect to specific page when rule is set

Tags: xml, iis, iis-10

I have url like :

```
http://localhost:8080/autoLogin?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiOTE3MzI4Nzk3MCIsIklkIjoiNTVkODI0ZWQtOWQ0Zi00MzQwLTljNGItNGYwMmI0MDMyNjA1IiwiRnVsbE5hbWUiOiLYs9is2KfYryDYstin2LHYuSIsIklTQWRtaW4iOiIyIiwibmJmIjoxNjg2MDQ1MjkwLCJleHAiOjE2ODYwNDYxOTAsImlhdCI6MTY4NjA0NTI5MH0.VT8E0dLN0QmWsuX_gGBaAKx3bJwQdRLtso9llVpc9a0&userId=55d824ed-9d4f-4340-9c4b-4f02b4032605
```

IIS can not redirect to autoLogin page normally . so I write a rule for it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.html" responseMode="File" />
        </httpErrors>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to dynamic URL" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^autoLogin$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^token=(.+)&amp;userId=(.+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:8080/autoLogin?token={C:1}&amp;userId={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But When I browse a url in forefox it thrown error:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
> this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> ```
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
> ```

And so in edge .

I was clear all cookie and cache but my problem does not fix yet.

Please help.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.